# Reliably (!) setting Series marker type (circle, quare, etc) using an expression

Tags: reporting-services

I am returning the textual equivalent values (Square, Circle, Diamond, Triangle, Cross, 4 Point Star, etc) of SSRS Series Marker Types in a dataset column and in the expression for Marker Type pointing to this column - for the most part this is working as one would expect, however for certain types (4 point star, 5 point star), no marker is being displayed.

As far as I can tell, specifying a text value equivalent to what is seen in the SSRS UI not a reliable way to go about this.

Actually, I now notice I am getting the following *Warning* in Visual Studio:

```
"The value of the Type property for the chart ‘Chart1’ is “5 point star”, which is not a valid Type.
```

Is there a "proper" way to go about this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

ChartMarkerTypes Enumeration:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reportingservices.rdlobjectmodel.chartmarkertypes(v=sql.120).aspx

For “5 point star” the value is "Star5"